# ASP.NET Core 3.0 - how to attach the Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have two Asp.Net Core projects - one is version 2.2. and one is version 3.0.

Each project is a brand new, empty MVC project created in Visual Studio.

I run each project by dropping to the command line and doing `dotnet run`.

I then debug my code as follows:

1. Open Task Manager and find the process Id for the `dotnet` process
2. Doing `Debug -> Attach to Process` in Visual Studio 2019

For the version 2.2 project, I can easily identify the correct `dotnet` process in Task Manager - it's the one showing the `dotnet exec` command pointing to my project's `.dll` file:

[image: Task Manager for version 2.2]

However - for the 3.0 project, the `dotnet` processes in Task Manager look like this:

[image]

None of the processes is clearly associated with my project's `.dll` files, and none of them allows me to debug my code using Attach to Process.

So my question is - is there a way of attaching Visual Studio's debugger to an Asp.Net Core 3.0 project when I run it using `dotnet run` ?

Comment: Instead of attaching the debugger, you can create a launch.json file with configurations to enable debugging in .Net core projects.

Comment: Thanks, I confirm in .net 5. to see my ProjectName.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the Asp.Net Core 3.0 project, when run using `dotnet run`, has a different entry in Task Manager than 2.2 - the `.exe` file produced by the build is what is displayed in Task Manager's details, and I can successfully attach to *this* process in Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue after *upgrading* a ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET Core 3.0. I have used a trick to find out the process I should attach to whenever needed:

- Run with Debug (F5)
- Attach to Process
- Find the process which is grayed out (already attached). This is the process that should be used to further process attachments

In my case the process was called `{AssemblyName}.exe`.

**Side note:** You can find [Reattach extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach) particularly useful for quickly reattaching (e.g. Ctrl-R Ctrl-1) to previous processes.

Comment: Hey that's a handy extension in your side note.